# How to utilize css of this style in LESS?

Tags: css, blueprint-css, less

I want to use some css framework but hate its unsemanticness. So I want to use LESS. The basic idea is mixin framework's css into my own classes. But I feel LESS can't handle some scenarios. For example, some classes are define in the framework as:

div.prepand = {...}
or
* html .span-1 = {...}

LESS mixin doesn't seem to support the above situations. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure which framework did you mean by saying that "some classes are define in the framework as:".

In Less, you don't declare mixins the way you showed it. You do it like so:

```
.my_mixin { ... }
```

And then below in the file you can (re)use it like so:

```
div.content {
   .my_mixin;
}
```

Other than that, I don't understand your question. You want to mixin framework's CSS into your own classes? What does that mean? You write CSS in Less or you don't ...

Comment: My problem is with mixin an existing framework like blueprint css. For styles in blueprint css like span-x is find since they are compatible with mixins. But in blueprint's ie hack file, there are some style definitions like: html body span-x {...}. Such definitions aren't able to be used as mixins.

Comment: i think you'd have to take Blueprint's hack file and write it in Less, writing mixins as needed.. it shouldn't be too complicated. and then just include it in your project and use mixins... i haven't worked with Blueprint for a while, i don't remember how complicated it is, but i'm sure it could be re-written in Less.

Comment: I agree. Rewrite is the only solution. Actually only the ie hack file is a little pain in ass. So ie sucks, not blueprint or less.

Answer (score 0):

I've just put together the grid portion of blueprint.css in LESS [here](http://github.com/davidpmccormick/Blueprint-LESS). You can set the column and gutter widths, then use mixins like this:

```
#header {
  .span(20);
  .prepend(2);
}
```

I've added a couple of example @media queries as well, allowing for responsive layouts.

I hope it might be of use to someone.